# Java Test package does not exist

Tags: java, package

Good morning,
I have the file Test.java that is in `/home`

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager out=new prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager();
        pack1.A a=new pack1.A();
        out.println(a.toString());
    }
}
```

that gives me the error:

```
Test.java:3: error: package prog.io does not exist
prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager out=new prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager();
^
Test.java:3: error: package prog.io does not exist
prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager out=new prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager();
^
Test.java:5: error: package pack1 does not exist
pack1.A a=new pack1.A();
^
Test.java:5: error: package pack1 does not exist
pack1.A a=new pack1.A();
^
4 errors
```

`pack1`, `pack2` and `prog.io` are in `/home` as well..Why it doesn't find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have set the classpath such that it can find the packages that you are using in your code.

Answer (score 3):

It is not sufficient to have the class files in the same directory. They must have the same package declaration as well.

Additionally `/home` must be part of your `Classpath`. If `/home` is your `Classpath` the files must be in subdirectories of `/home`:

```
/home/prog/io
    ConsoleOutputManager.class
/home/pack1
    A.class
/home
    Test.class
```

`ConsoleOutputManager.java` should have a declaration like `package prog.io;` before any `import` or `class` statements. `A.java` should have `package pack1;`.

With that, you can run your class informing the classpath using:

```
java -cp /home Test
```

And it will find its dependencies.

You can also place your dependencies in a JAR file with that same structure, and then include the JAR file in your classpath as well:

```
java -cp yourJar.jar:/home Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have package declaration in your ConsoleOutputManager class as well. It should be:

```
package prog.io;
```

as the first line in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Your source files are not organised into packages properly or the packages are missing. Your class file defines

```
prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager out=new prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager();
pack1.A a=new pack1.A();
```

so, JVM will look for class `ConsoleOutputManager` in `prog.io` package and class `A` in `pack1` package and couldn't be found and throws `package doesn't exist` error. The solution is to add the missing packages sources in build path and keep your source files organised