# I cannot run the code with external jar in Terminal but I can run it in any IDE

Tags: java, import, jar

So I am new to the java.

I have these external two jar files. I properly imported them into my IDE: exclips.
When I use the IDE the code, it is running and using the external jars. However, when I am trying to use the terminal of MAC, it is giving a mistake of no two jars like this

> testten.java:3: error: package stdlib does not exist import

In my IDE the `testten.java` is running and I have the `testten.class.` but in Terminal

How can I solve it ??

Comment: Add the external jars to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the program as a runnable jar file. Then on PC navigate to the location of the jar file in CMD and type "java -jar {Name of jar file}.jar". On a mac navigate to the location of the file in Terminal and type "java -jar {Name of jar file}.jar".
 Hope this helps :) 
 if the issue continuous try checking out this: [Java Test package does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967013/java-test-package-does-not-exist)